# I should use php or python to make web crawler?

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, web-scraping, web-crawler

I learning about web-crawling and I and don't know whether to use php or python. I want to make a website that takes information from  another website and automatically updating.
And does it possible to make a decent website with python? or I have to paste the information from python to html or php?

Comment: you can user [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) a fast web crawling framework.

Comment: I have been using PHP for years to make web crawlers. Unless you are requiring good resource usage etc. PHP will do the job. Python is little different. If I had more time I'd want to use another language though, C, golang, or even Bash would be better for heavy duty. But for something simple PHP, or Python will suffice. I would go with what you are most comfortable with.

Answer (score 2):

It depends a bit one the nuances. PHP is a language mainly used to develop websites (to present them), whereas Python is used for both programming websites and programming other applications. Thus, it depends on how application-like the scraping will be or how much it will be included into the (presentational) website.

Python is well-suited for scraping tasks as it has a lot of third party libraries (Scrapy, BeautifulSoup, lxml, request, ...) and also built in libraries for requesting URLs. With PHP you will have a harder life requesting other websites. As said, it is mainly focused on building an own website.

Also it of course depends on your skill level in each language.

I'd split the application into two parts anyway:

- presentation logic (your own website)
- scraping logic (scraping other websites)

Both will be connected through a database. The scraping logic collects information and stores it into the database. The presentation logic takes information from the database and displays it to the user as HTML.

For the scraping part, you then want to prefer Python over PHP. And for the presentation part, it actually does not matter and is a matter of preference or knowledge.

Comment: thx. How exactly could I take the python scaring and display it on html or php?

Comment: With the database in between. Just think of it as a website which uses data from a database to display everything. However, there is a second program running which fills the database continuously.